# BlocProvider inside initstate that receive value from blocbuilder

Tags: flutter

i curious how to call BlocProvider inside inistate that retrieve value from BlocBuilder.
usually inside widget i call Blocbuilder to retrieve a string and then the string value i can pass to Bloc provider so will run fetch data.

i try in inistate like below :

```
  void initState(){
super.initState();
BlocBuilder<idoutletbloc,String>(
    builder: (context,idoutlet)=>BlocProvider.of<tablelistbloc>(context).add(idoutlet);
);}
```

but it said "The return is void isn't Widget", as defined by anonymous closure.
how i can retrieve a value from  idoutletbloc and then i can add BlocProvider.of(context).add(idoutlet) ??

i can't find it anywhere

here my bloc code

this is my bloc string value

```
class idoutletbloc extends Bloc<String, String>{
@override
String get initialState => '';
@override
Stream<String> mapEventToState(String idoutlet) async* {
yield idoutlet.toString();
}
}
```

my bloc that fetch data that need to receive a value

```
class viewtableactivebloc extends Bloc<String, List<ViewTableActives>>{
@override
List<ViewTableActives> get initialState => [];
@override
Stream<List<ViewTableActives>> mapEventToState(String event) async*{
List<ViewTableActives> viewtableactive =[];
try{
final response = await http.post(BaseUrl.ViewTableActive,
body: {
        "ID_Outlet": event,
      });
  final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (data.length != 0) {
    print("----------START Print View Table Active----------");
    data.forEach((api) {
      viewtableactive.add(
        ViewTableActives(
          api['ID_Transactions'],
          api['ID_Customer'],
        )
      );
      print("Print View Table Actibe : "
          "ID_Transactions : "+api['ID_Transactions']+", "
          "ID_Customer : "+api['ID_Customer']+", "
      );
    });
    print("----------END Print View Table Active----------");
    print("viewtableactivebloc : sukses");
  } else {
    viewtableactive =[];
    print('data kosong');
  }

}
catch(e){
  print("Error ViewTableActive :");
  print(e);
}
yield viewtableactive;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current state of the bloc like:

BlocProvider.of(context).state;

or via the shorthand

context.bloc().state;